# InDesign When clicking W (Display mode) Images & background dissapear

Tags: adobe-indesign

You can see on the pictures things are dissapearing.

When i click on the W button the text and background are dissapearing, i can't find the problem, does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to *only* in the thumbnail previews for the Pages panel?  I mean, they are thumbnails and only meant to be a clue as to contents.

Comment: No, when I export it the images/background are also gone, (see photo 1). It only stays if I group EVERYTHING. It will be exported as the photo 1. :)

Comment: We can’t really see in the pictures what, if anything, is disappearing, because we don’t know what it’s supposed to look like. You’ve shown page thumbnails and one version of a spread, which doesn’t say much – which is even the correct one? Please show the actual spread looking correct and incorrect and make it clear which is which.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the content that disappears might be on a layer with the print attribute turned off.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of this. I think this could be it!

Comment: Thanks! This might be it

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using the very latest update, it is known that Adobe sometimes *accidentally* introduce random bugs with new updates.

This is probably a bug of some sort, or a local problem with settings or refresh issue. Depending on your hardware performance, the machine might be too slow, or too quick, to process the <kbd>W</kbd> preview properly.

No reason to worry, hitting <kbd>W</kbd> is not supposed to delete anything from the document, the artwork is probably still there and the pages panel is just a preview.

I tried to replicate this on my InDesign and it does not happen. Hitting <kbd>W</kbd> does not affect the previews in the pages panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its not only when i press the W button when i export it some things are not showing. If you look at page 2 in the first picture and compare it to the second picture, you see the last collum is without a background. When i export it the same thing happens, i found out only when i group everything it wil export normally.

Comment: This is strange. You either have some missing links then, or otherwise this cannot possibly be resolved without looking at the actual files. If there's something wrong with your copy of ID we also won't be able to fix it for you.